# Vuex2.0 how to configure and how to getters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Early today try vuex 2.1.2 vue:2.1.0, the directory structure is as follows

[image: file]

**store.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import common from './common/store'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        common
    }
})
```

**mutations-types.js：**

```
export const ADD_NUM = "ADD_NUM"
```

**common/store.js：**

```
import * as types from '../mutations-types'

const state = {
    num : 1 
}

const mutations = {

    [types.ADD_NUM] : function(state){
        state.num = state.num + 1;
    },
}

export default {
    state,
    mutations
}
```

**common/actions.js：**

```
import * as types from '../mutations-types'

export default {
    setNum : store => {
        store.dispatch(types.ADD_NUM)
    },
}
```

common/getters.js:

```
export default {
    getNum : state => {
        state.common.num
    },
}
```

**Then get the value of num in Hello.vue through getters**

[image: template]

**In the vue entry file main.js, a store is injected**

**run error:**

> Property or method "getNum" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render

Why is this error reported? Does this directory structure and code correct?

Comment: Try to use mapGetters, it works better and simplier for me: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html Also, in the getNum method in getters.js you are not returning anything, you would need to either remove the brackets or to return state.common.num

Comment: I do not quite understand "form'vuex '"  "vuex" how to find gettersMap

Comment: I don't undertand your last comment, seems to me like Google Translate is being Google Translate.

Comment: Thank you, really mapGetters

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I did not read the official documents

Using mapGetters solves the problem

THANKS @Potray

I refer to the official demo [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart)